# kendo ui listview selected item index

Tags: ajax, json, listview, user-interface, kendo-ui

i have a div defined for my listview like this:

```
<div id="carrierList"></div>
```

Here is my script that defines the listview and its datasource ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

     var t94StragglerCarriers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/MenuTrain/T94StragglerCarriers",                    
                dataType: "json"                   
            },
            schema: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "string" },                          
                        val: { type: "string" } 
                    }                               
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging : true 
        }
    });

    var carriers = $("#carrierList").kendoListView({
        dataSource: t94StragglerCarriers,
        selectable: true,
        pageable : true ,
        change: onChange,
        template : kendo.template($("#carrierTemplate").html())
    }).data("kendoListView");



    function onChange() {          
        var index = carriers.select().index();
        var item = carriers.dataSource.view()[index];
        console.log("Item " + index + " selected. Guid = " + item.id);
    }

});
```

Here is the template definition for my listview :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl"  id="carrierTemplate">    
<div id='carrierListVal_#=val#_#=id#' class='k-textbox'>#=val#</div>           
<br/>
```

Here is the action method on my controller :

```
public JsonResult T94StragglerCarriers( [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {           
         return Json(t94RailcarRepository.CarriersWithStragglers(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Here is the json string returned by the server :

```
[{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"CHTT"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"CMO "},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"CTCX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"DBUX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"GATX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"MWCX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"NDYX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"PLMX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"TAEX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"TCIX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"TEIX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"TILX"},{"id":"10eac72a-d62d-434f-8505-4869cdb27b04","val":"UP  "},{"id":"ffbcdb6c-4d3a-45f6-8ef6-ada5f28ba44b","val":"MDXx"}]
```

My problem is that from the onChange event handler, when i try to get the index of the selected listview item, like so :

```
 var index = carriers.select().index();
```

it is returned a value as if each field in the json string is an element. For example , the first object's id field would be index 0 , and it's val fiedl would be index 1. and so on. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong to get the index of the selected listview item? or is there something wrong with the json string i don't see?

Comment: Can you add what `carriers.select()` is returning? Do the list view items look like you expect them to?

Comment: check this,var data = t94StragglerCarriers .view(),
                 selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {             var Index = data[$(item).index()]       });